# Parameterized Async function returning Promise { "_40": 0, "_55": "English", "_65": 1, "_72": null, }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native, async-await

[CLOSED]
**How to get the 'English' out of the promise object which is unneccesary**

> **Async Functions -> parameterized**

```js
const getLanguageNamefromCode = async (lng_code) => {
  let response, langData, lang;
  try {
    response = await fetch(
      `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/lang/${lng_code}?fields=languages`
    );
    langData = await response.json();
    // console.log(langData[0].languages[0]);
    if (langData[0].languages[0].iso639_1 === lng_code) {
      lang = langData[0].languages[0].name;
      console.log(lang);
    }
    return lang;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

> **calling it from inside a for loop and sending in a parameter**

```js
      const loadedTrendingMovies = [];
      const loadedTrendingMoviesLength = trendingMovies.results.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // let credits;
        hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
          (userMovie) =>
            userMovie.id === trendingMovies.results[i].id.toString()
        );

        loadedTrendingMovies.push(
          new Movie(
            trendingMovies.results[i].id.toString(),
            trendingMovies.results[i].media_type === "movie"
              ? trendingMovies.results[i].title
              : trendingMovies.results[i].name,
            posterBaseUrl + trendingMovies.results[i].poster_path,
            trendingMovies.results[i].media_type === "movie"
              ? trendingMovies.results[i].release_date
              : trendingMovies.results[i].first_air_date,
            [],
            trendingMovies.results[i].overview,
            trendingMovies.results[i].vote_average,
            getLanguageNamefromCode(trendingMovies.results[i].original_language),
            hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""
          )
        );
      }
```

How to get the value from the promise returned by the getLanguagefromCode Async Method.

> > This is my MoviesScreen functional component , i am using redux

```js
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  RefreshControl,
} from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import MovieItem from "../components/MovieItem";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import * as MoviesAction from "../store/actions/MoviesAction";
import * as UserActions from "../store/actions/UserActions";
import Colors from "../constants/Colors";

import { useScrollToTop } from "@react-navigation/native";

import SkeletonContent from "react-native-skeleton-content";
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

const stories = createSelector(
  (state) => state.Movies.movies,
  (movies) => movies
);
const newReleases = createSelector(
  (state) => state.Movies.new_releases,
  (new_releases) => new_releases
);
const newTVShows = createSelector(
  (state) => state.Movies.new_tv_shows,
  (new_tv_shows) => new_tv_shows
);
const Anime = createSelector(
  (state) => state.Movies.anime,
  (anime) => anime
);
const MoviesScreen = (props) => {
  const Stories = useSelector(stories);
  const new_releases = useSelector(newReleases);
  console.log(" movie screen rendered", new_releases);
  const new_tv_shows = useSelector(newTVShows);
  const anime = useSelector(Anime);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);

  useScrollToTop(scrollRef);

  const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    loadScreen().then(() => setRefreshing(false));
  }, [setRefreshing, loadScreen]);

  const loadScreen = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(MoviesAction.loadAll());
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    loadScreen().then(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  const renderTrendingMoviesItem = ({ item }) => (
    <SkeletonContent
      boneColor="#303030"
      highlightColor="#252525"
      containerStyle={styles.new_releases}
      isLoading={loading || refreshing}
      layout={[styles.cinemaSkeleton]}
    >
      <MovieItem
        style={styles.new_releases}
        id={item.id}
        movieTitle={item.title}
        posterUrl={item.posterUrl}
        year={item.year}
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate({
            name: "MoviesDetailScreen",
            params: {
              movieId: item.id,
              movieTitle: item.title,
              moviesType: "Movies",
            },
          });
        }}
      />
    </SkeletonContent>
  );

  const renderStoriesItem = ({ item }) => (
    <SkeletonContent
      boneColor="#303030"
      highlightColor="#252525"
      containerStyle={{
        ...styles.storyItem,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        marginVertical: 7.5,
      }}
      isLoading={loading || refreshing}
      layout={[
        {
          key: "story",
          width: 80,
          height: 80,
          borderRadius: 40,
          marginHorizontal: 10,
          marginVertical: 7.5,
        },
      ]}
    >
      <MovieItem
        style={styles.storyItem}
        footerStyle={{ opacity: 0 }}
        imageStyle={styles.storyImage}
        id={item.id}
        posterUrl={item.posterUrl}
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate({
            name: "NewReleasesModalScreen",
            params: {
              movieTitle: item.title,
              posterUrl: item.posterUrl,
              movieId: item.id,
            },
          });
        }}
      />
    </SkeletonContent>
  );

  const renderTrendingTVItem = ({ item }) => (
    <SkeletonContent
      boneColor="#303030"
      highlightColor="#252525"
      containerStyle={styles.new_releases}
      isLoading={loading || refreshing}
      layout={[styles.cinemaSkeleton]}
    >
      <MovieItem
        style={styles.new_releases}
        id={item.id}
        movieTitle={item.title}
        posterUrl={item.posterUrl}
        year={item.year}
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate({
            name: "MoviesDetailScreen",
            params: {
              movieId: item.id,
              movieTitle: item.title,
              moviesType: "TV",
            },
          });
        }}
      />
    </SkeletonContent>
  );

  const renderAnimeItem = ({ item }) => (
    <SkeletonContent
      boneColor="#303030"
      highlightColor="#252525"
      containerStyle={styles.new_releases}
      isLoading={loading || refreshing}
      layout={[styles.cinemaSkeleton]}
    >
      <MovieItem
        style={styles.new_releases}
        id={item.id}
        movieTitle={item.title}
        posterUrl={item.posterUrl}
        year={item.year}
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate({
            name: "MoviesDetailScreen",
            params: {
              movieId: item.id,
              movieTitle: item.title,
              moviesType: "anime",
              goToAnime: true,
            },
          });
        }}
      />
    </SkeletonContent>
  );

  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={scrollRef}
      style={styles.screen}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={onRefresh}
          tintColor={Colors.lightblue}
        />
      }
    >
      {/* new releases stories */}
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <SkeletonContent
        boneColor="#303030"
        highlightColor="#252525"
        containerStyle={styles.headerCont}
        isLoading={loading || refreshing}
        layout={[styles.headerTextSkeleton]}
      >
        <View style={styles.headerCont}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}> New Releases </Text>
        </View>
      </SkeletonContent>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal={true}
          data={Stories}
          renderItem={renderStoriesItem}
        />
      </View>

      {/* new releases stories */}
      {/*...

      TOP MOVIE THAT WEEK 

      ...
      */}

      <View>
        <SkeletonContent
          boneColor="#303030"
          containerStyle={styles.headerCont}
          highlightColor="#252525"
          containerStyle={styles.headerCont}
          isLoading={loading || refreshing}
          layout={[styles.headerTextSkeleton]}
        >
          <View style={styles.headerCont}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate({
                  name: "SeeAllScreen",
                  params: {
                    new_releases: true,
                    headerTitle: "Trending Movies",
                  },
                });
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}> Movies </Text>
                <Ionicons
                  style={{ marginStart: 5 }}
                  name="ios-arrow-forward"
                  size={22}
                  color={Colors.lightblue}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        </SkeletonContent>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal={true}
          data={new_releases}
          renderItem={renderTrendingMoviesItem}
        />
      </View>

      {/* TV SHOWS */}

      <View>
        <SkeletonContent
          boneColor="#303030"
          containerStyle={styles.headerCont}
          highlightColor="#252525"
          containerStyle={styles.headerCont}
          isLoading={loading || refreshing}
          layout={[styles.headerTextSkeleton]}
        >
          <View style={styles.headerCont}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate({
                  name: "SeeAllScreen",
                  params: {
                    new_tv_shows: true,
                    headerTitle: "Trending TV Shows",
                  },
                });
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}> TV Shows </Text>
                <Ionicons
                  style={{ marginStart: 5 }}
                  name="ios-arrow-forward"
                  size={22}
                  color={Colors.lightblue}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        </SkeletonContent>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal={true}
          data={new_tv_shows}
          renderItem={renderTrendingTVItem}
        />
      </View>

      {/* Anime */}

      <View>
        <SkeletonContent
          boneColor="#303030"
          containerStyle={styles.headerCont}
          highlightColor="#252525"
          containerStyle={styles.headerCont}
          isLoading={loading || refreshing}
          layout={[styles.headerTextSkeleton]}
        >
          <View style={styles.headerCont}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate({
                  name: "SeeAllScreen",
                  params: {
                    moviesType: "anime",
                    goToAnime: true,
                    headerTitle: "Trending Anime",
                  },
                });
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}> Anime </Text>
                <Ionicons
                  style={{ marginStart: 5 }}
                  name="ios-arrow-forward"
                  size={22}
                  color={Colors.lightblue}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        </SkeletonContent>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal={true}
          data={anime}
          renderItem={renderAnimeItem}
        />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

> This is the actions file

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const SEARCH_MOVIES = "SEARCH_MOVIES";
export const LOAD_MOVIES_WITH_GENRES = "LOAD_MOVIES_WITH_GENRES";
export const CLEAR_SEARCH_LIST = "CLEAR_SEARCH_LIST";
export const CLEAR_GENRE_SCREEN = "CLEAR_GENRE_SCREEN";
export const LOAD_ALL = "LOAD_ALL";

import Movie from "../../models/Movie";

import config from "../../config";
import Cast from "../../models/CastMember";

const getCredits = async (index) => {
  let response, creditsData;
  try {
    response = await fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${resData.results[index].id}?api_key=${config.TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US&append_to_response=credits`
    );
    creditsData = await response.json();
    // console.log("credits", creditsData);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  const castMembers = [];
  const length =
    creditsData.credits.cast.length > 10 ? 10 : creditsData.credits.cast.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    castMembers.push(
      new Cast(
        creditsData.credits.cast[i].id,
        creditsData.credits.cast[i].character,
        creditsData.credits.cast[i].name,
        posterBaseUrl + creditsData.credits.cast[i].profile_path
      )
    );
  }

  console.log(castMembers);

  return { cast: castMembers };
};

const getLanguageNamefromCode = async (lng_code) => {
  let response, langData, lang;
  try {
    response = await fetch(
      `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/lang/${lng_code}?fields=languages`
    );
    langData = await response.json();
    // console.log(langData[0].languages[0]);
    if (langData[0].languages[0].iso639_1 === lng_code) {
      lang = langData[0].languages[0].name;
      console.log(lang);
    }
    return lang;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};

export const clearSearchList = () => {
  return { type: CLEAR_SEARCH_LIST };
};

export const clearGenreScreen = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_GENRE_SCREEN,
  };
};

export const loadAll = () => {
  const posterBaseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
  let hasUserSaved;
  const loadedStories = [];
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      //stories response
      const moviesResponse = await fetch(
        `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${config.OMDB_API_KEY}&s=tokyo`
      );
      // trending movies
      const TrendingMoviesResponse = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=${config.TMDB_API_KEY}`
      );
      // trending TV
      const trendingTVResponse = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=${config.TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&first_air_date_year=2020&page=1&with_original_language=en`
      );
      // trending Anime
      const trendingAnimeResponse = await fetch(
        `https://kitsu.io/api/edge/trending/anime`,
        {
          method: "GET",
        }
      );

      if (
        !moviesResponse.ok ||
        !TrendingMoviesResponse.ok ||
        !trendingTVResponse.ok ||
        !trendingAnimeResponse.ok
      ) {
        throw new Error("failed response");
      }

      const movies = await moviesResponse.json();
      const trendingMovies = await TrendingMoviesResponse.json();
      const trendingTV = await trendingTVResponse.json();
      const trendingAnime = await trendingAnimeResponse.json();
      // console.log('Trending Movies',resData);
      // console.log("NEW RELEASES", resData);

      //stories array

      const loadedMoviesLength = movies.Search.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        loadedStories.push(
          new Movie(
            movies.Search[i].imdbID,
            movies.Search[i].Title,
            movies.Search[i].Poster,
            movies.Search[i].Year
          )
        );
      }

      //trending movies array

      // console.log("loadedTrendingMovies", loadedTrendingMovies);
      let loadedTrendingMovies=[];

      const loadedTrendingMoviesLength = trendingMovies.results.length;

      // loadedTrendingMovies =
      Promise.all(
        trendingMovies.results
          .slice(0, 5) // use slice instead of a loop
          .map((
            trendingMovie // map movie to [language,movie]
          ) =>
            getLanguageNamefromCode(
              // get async language
              trendingMovie.original_language
              // resolve to [language,movie]
            ).then((language) => [language, trendingMovie])
          ) // sorry, forgot to return here
      )
        .then((
          results // results is [[language,movie],[language,movie]]
        ) =>
          results.map(([language, trendingMovie]) => {
            const hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
              (userMovie) => userMovie.id === trendingMovie.id.toString()
              // snippet does not have conditional chaining
            );
            return new Movie( // create new Movie
              trendingMovie.id.toString(),
              trendingMovie.media_type === "movie"
                ? trendingMovie.title
                : trendingMovie.name,
              posterBaseUrl + trendingMovie.poster_path,
              trendingMovie.media_type === "movie"
                ? trendingMovie.release_date
                : trendingMovie.first_air_date,
              [],
              trendingMovie.overview,
              trendingMovie.vote_average,
              language,
              hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""
            );
          })
        )
        .then((movies) => {
          // loadedTrendingMovies.push(movies);
          loadedTrendingMovies = [...loadedTrendingMovies, ...movies];
          console.log("loadedTrendingMovies", loadedTrendingMovies);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));

      // trending TV Shows
      const loadedNewTVShows = [];
      const TVShowsLength = trendingTV.results.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // let credits;
        hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
          (userMovie) => userMovie.id === trendingTV.results[i].id.toString()
        );
        // let cast = getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast);
        // console.log("CAST", cast);
        loadedNewTVShows.push(
          new Movie(
            trendingTV.results[i].id.toString(),
            trendingTV.results[i].name,
            posterBaseUrl + trendingTV.results[i].poster_path,
            trendingTV.results[i].first_air_date.toString().substr(0, 5),
            // getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast),
            // getCredits(i)
            //   .then((results) => {
            //     console.log("success", results.cast);
            //     return results.cast;
            //   })
            //   .catch((err) => console.log("cast error", err)),
            [],
            trendingTV.results[i].overview,
            trendingTV.results[i].vote_average,
            // getLanguageNamefromCode(trendingTV.results[i].original_language),
            hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""
          )
        );
      }

      const loadedAnime = [];
      const AnimeLength = trendingAnime.data.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // let credits;
        hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
          (userMovie) => userMovie.id === trendingAnime.data[i].id.toString()
        );
        // let cast = getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast);
        // console.log("CAST", cast);
        loadedAnime.push(
          new Movie(
            trendingAnime.data[i].id,
            trendingAnime.data[i].attributes.canonicalTitle,
            trendingAnime.data[i].attributes.posterImage.medium,
            trendingAnime.data[i].attributes.createdAt.toString().substr(0, 4),
            // getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast),
            [],
            trendingAnime.data[i].attributes.synopsis,
            trendingAnime.data[i].attributes.vote_average,
            "Japanese",
            hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""
          )
        );
      }

      dispatch({
        type: LOAD_ALL,
        movies: loadedStories,
        new_releases: loadedTrendingMovies,
        new_tv_shows: loadedNewTVShows,
        anime: loadedAnime,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};

export const searchMovies = (MovieTitle) => {
  let response;
  let hasUserSaved;
  const posterBaseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      response = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${config.TMDB_API_KEY}&query=${MovieTitle}&page=1`
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("failed response");
      }

      const resData = await response.json();
      console.log("search results: ", resData);

      const searchedMovies = [];
      const length = resData.results.length;

      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
          (userMovie) => userMovie.id === resData.results[i].id
        );
        searchedMovies.push(
          new Movie(
            resData.results[i].id.toString(),
            resData.results[i].title,
            posterBaseUrl + resData.results[i].poster_path,
            resData.results[i].release_date,
            // getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast),
            [],
            resData.results[i].overview,
            resData.results[i].vote_average,
            // getLanguageNamefromCode(resData.results[i].original_language),
            hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""
          )
        );
      }
      dispatch({
        type: SEARCH_MOVIES,
        searched_movies: searchedMovies,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};

export const loadMoviesWithGenres = (genreId) => {
  let response;
  let hasUserSaved;
  const posterBaseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    await dispatch(clearGenreScreen());
    try {
      response = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?with_genres=${genreId}&api_key=${config.TMDB_API_KEY}`
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("failed response");
      }

      const resData = await response.json();
      // console.log(resData);

      const loadedMoviesWRTGenre = [];
      const length = resData.results.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
          (userMovie) => userMovie.id === resData.results[i].id.toString()
        );
        // let cast = getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast)
        // console.log("CAST", cast);
        loadedMoviesWRTGenre.push(
          new Movie(
            resData.results[i].id.toString(),
            resData.results[i].title,
            posterBaseUrl + resData.results[i].poster_path,
            resData.results[i].release_date,
            // cast,
            // getCredits(i),
            [],
            resData.results[i].overview,
            resData.results[i].vote_average,
            // getLanguageNamefromCode(resData.results[i].original_language),
            hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""
          )
        );
      }

      console.log("moviesWRTGenre", loadedMoviesWRTGenre);

      dispatch({
        type: LOAD_MOVIES_WITH_GENRES,
        moviesWRTGenre: loadedMoviesWRTGenre,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};
```

> when i am logging the array in the actions file, it shows the perfect result , i.e.,

```
loadedTrendingMovies Array [
  Movie {
    "cast": Array [],
    "id": "385103",
    "language": "English",
    "location": "",
    "plot": "In Scooby-Doo’s greatest adventure yet, see the never-before told story of how lifelong friends Scooby and Shaggy first met and how they joined forces with young detectives Fred, Velma, and Daphne to form the famous Mystery Inc. Now, with hundreds of cases solved, Scooby and the gang face their biggest, toughest mystery ever: an evil plot to unleash the ghost dog Cerberus upon the world. As they race to stop this global “dogpocalypse,” the gang discovers that Scooby has a secret legacy and an epic destiny greater than anyone ever imagined.",
    "posterUrl": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/zG2l9Svw4PTldWJAzC171Y3d6G8.jpg",
    "ratings": 8.3,
    "title": "Scoob!",
    "year": "2020-05-15",
  },
  Movie {
    "cast": Array [],
    "id": "79680",
    "language": "English",
    "location": "",
    "plot": "Set more than seven years after the world has become a frozen wasteland, the remnants of humanity inhabit a gigantic, perpetually-moving train that circles the globe as class warfare, social injustice and the politics of survival play out.",
    "posterUrl": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/n6UNHZoiYj81abwmG38HbNjflDx.jpg",
    "ratings": 3,
    "title": "Snowpiercer",
    "year": "2020-05-17",
  },
  Movie {
    "cast": Array [],
    "id": "80986",
    "language": "English",
    "location": "",
    "plot": "Courtney Whitmore, a smart, athletic and above all else kind girl, discovers her step-father has a secret; he used to be the sidekick to a superhero. \"Borrowing\" the long-lost hero’s cosmic staff, she becomes the unlikely inspiration for an entirely new generation of superheroes.",
    "posterUrl": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/JJxVsQPPiuLcArALotMHsCubeo.jpg",
    "ratings": 9,
    "title": "Stargirl",
    "year": "2020-05-18",
  },
  Movie {
    "cast": Array [],
    "id": "530915",
    "language": "English",
    "location": "",
    "plot": "At the height of the First World War, two young British soldiers must cross enemy territory and deliver a message that will stop a deadly attack on hundreds of soldiers.",
    "posterUrl": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/AuGiPiGMYMkSosOJ3BQjDEAiwtO.jpg",
    "ratings": 7.9,
    "title": "1917",
    "year": "2019-12-25",
  },
  Movie {
    "cast": Array [],
    "id": "582596",
    "language": "English",
    "location": "",
    "plot": "A guy meets the woman of his dreams and invites her to his company's corporate retreat, but realizes he sent the invite to the wrong person.",
    "posterUrl": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/A2YlIrzypvhS3vTFMcDkG3xLvac.jpg",
    "ratings": 6.1,
    "title": "The Wrong Missy",
    "year": "2020-05-13",
  },
]
```

> so i console log in the beginning of the MovieScreen Components (it is the first screen that loads up when my react native app launches) to see if the array is empty

```
 movie screen rendered Array []
 movie screen rendered Array []
 movie screen rendered Array []
 movie screen rendered Array []
```

> Also i do not know why did it console logged i.e., re-rendered 4 times ,
>   do you have any ideas ?

[Here is its github repository if you want to check just npm install with expo](https://github.com/Abhishek12345679/moviesTrackerApp)

Comment: `Object.values(x).filter(p=>typeof(p)=="string")`

Comment: Here x is nothing but your object

Comment: You can even check all the language instead of typeof

Comment: `getLanguageNamefromCode` will return a Promise ... either use `.then` or await (the latter is easiest solution to your code where you USE getLanguageNamefromCode)

Comment: but we can't await outside an async function right ? @JaromandaX

Comment: @SourabhSomani where do i insert this code ? i did not get it ?

Comment: correct, so that's when you need to use `.then` - but that will require a rewrite of the code that uses the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following should work (please note that this also returns a promise that resolves to an array of movies).

```js
   const loadedTrendingMovies = await Promise.all(
      trendingMovies.results
        .slice(0, 5) // use slice instead of a loop
        .map((trendingMovie) => // map movie to [language,movie]
          getLanguageNamefromCode(// get async language
            trendingMovie.original_language
          // resolve to [language,movie]
          ).then((language) => [language, trendingMovie]) 
        ) // sorry, forgot to return here
    ).then((results) => // results is [[language,movie],[language,movie]]
      results.map(
        ([language, trendingMovie]) =>
          new Movie( // create new Movie
            trendingMovie.id.toString(),
            trendingMovie.media_type === 'movie'
              ? trendingMovie.title
              : trendingMovie.name,
            posterBaseUrl + trendingMovie.poster_path,
            trendingMovie.media_type === 'movie'
              ? trendingMovie.release_date
              : trendingMovie.first_air_date,
            [],
            trendingMovie.overview,
            trendingMovie.vote_average,
            language,
            getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
              (userMovie) =>
                userMovie.id === trendingMovie.id.toString()
            // if you don't have optional chaining you can get location
            //  first the way you did before
            )?.location || '' 
          )
      )
    );
```

Working example

```js
const trendingMovies = {
  results: [
    {
      original_language: 1,
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      original_language: 2,
      id: 2,
    },
  ],
};
const getLanguageNamefromCode = (lang) =>
  Promise.resolve(`language is: ${lang}`);
function Movie(id, language, location) {
  this.id = id;
  this.language = language;
  this.location = location;
}
const getState = () => ({
  UserMovies: {
    userMovies: [{ id: '1', location: 'location 1' }],
  },
});
Promise.all(
  trendingMovies.results
    .slice(0, 5) // use slice instead of a loop
    .map((trendingMovie) =>
      // map movie to [language,movie]
      getLanguageNamefromCode(
        // get async language
        trendingMovie.original_language
        // resolve to [language,movie]
      ).then((language) => [language, trendingMovie])
    )
)
  .then((
    results // results is [[language,movie],[language,movie]]
  ) =>
    results.map(([language, trendingMovie]) => {
      const userMovie = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
        (userMovie) =>
          userMovie.id === trendingMovie.id.toString()
        // snippet does not have conditional chaining
      );
      return new Movie( // create new Movie
        trendingMovie.id.toString(),
        language,
        userMovie ? userMovie.location : ''
      );
    })
  )
  .then((movies) => console.log('movies:', movies));
```

Comment: should i replace this with my for loop?

Comment: @Abhishek  In this case `Promise.all(arr.slice(0,5).map...` is cleaner than `const tmp = [];for(){tmp.push} Promise.all(tmp)...` so I would advice you do so. Also when arr[4] is undefined your for loop would generate an error but the slice won't

Comment: yeah how did u know ? the loop sometimes does do that . thanks. @HMR can you link me to some doc or article where i can learn about this type of approach

Comment: @Abhishek [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: invalid attempt to destructure non iterable instance , i am getting this error !!

Comment: @Abhishek Sorry, there was an error, the map function did not return anything, I updated the answer and added a working example.

Comment: i have to store the array returned by Promise.all in the variable loadedTrendingMovies to be dispatched

Comment: @Abhishek In the example you can see it logging the movies, you can dispatch there.

Comment: ` // .then((movies) => {
        // console.log("loadedTrendingMovies", loadedTrendingMovies);
        // return (loadedTrendingMovies = movies);
        // })` how to sore the movies into another variable so that i can be stored in redux... @HMR

Comment: @Abhishek Can you update your question with the code you are currently using and the issue you are having?

Comment: I Updated the question with the broader code. have a look .